# Angular detect AJAX post upload after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I've got a function that uploads a file:

```
$scope.uploadEditor = function(files) {
        //progressBar.start();

        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("file", files[0]);
        GridOptionsService.state.editors.selectedFile = files[0].name;
        $('#dummyInput').val(GridOptionsService.state.editors.selectedFile);

        $('#btn_Install').addClass('disabled');
        DataContext.uploadEditor(fd).then(function(/*data*/){

            //progressBar.stop();
            $('#btn_Install').removeClass('disabled');
            $scope.cancelUpload();
            DataContext.getEditors().then(function(data){
                $scope.myData = data;

            }).catch(function(reason){


            });
        }).catch(function(reason){
            MessageBus.emitMsg('error',reason);
            console.log('caught1: ');
            $scope.cancelUpload();
            $('#btn_Install').removeClass('disabled');

            console.log($('#fileSelector'));

        });
    };
    //this removes the file name chosen from the input type file control
    $scope.cancelUpload = function(){
        $('#fileSelector').val('');
        $('#dummyInput').val('');
    };
```

While the file is uploading, the user can refresh the page and then the state of the selected file name is lost.  GridOptionsService.state.editors.selectedFile is the text of the file name that the user chose to upload.  Is there anyway to persist that information inside of the file input control after a page refresh?

Comment: just tell them not to leave or their file will be lost

Comment: @charlietfl is it possible to do it is what i'm asking :) but your solution is the best.

Comment: not likely any simple solutions that wouldn't require storing something locally when they start, then checking that storage on page load. I doubt you could pick up where they left off, just tell them they screwed up and need to do it again